# Export a function in js with import and export

Tags: javascript

I have following function in `actions.js` file

```
export const mockFunction = () => {
  return true
}
```

I have an `index.js` file, where I want to export this function to the rest of the app

```
import * as actions from './actions'
export {actions}
```

I get as error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/providers/xxform_provider/actions.jsx
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/client/xxxx/src/providers/xxform_provider/actions.jsx'
```

I am not using webpack, actually I guess no, if I have a look at my package.json

I am using `create-react-app`

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Does anybody know what `create-react-app` uses as a js bundler? I can not tell from the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react_porter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.40",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-swipe": "^6.0.4",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "swipe-js-iso": "^2.1.5",
    "swipejs": "^2.2.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bad config, are you using webpack to compile, what's your config look like.  From the error it looks like it's trying to load jsx files as the default.

Comment: @Keith that must be, because in another project in my company it's working this syntax. Not sure which js compiler create-react-app uses, couldn't find any info

Answer (score 0):

actions.js

```
const mockFunction = () => true;

export default mockFunction;
```

index.js

```
import mockFunction from './actions';
```

i hope this helps